# Зависимость height от widht (в %)

Tags: вёрстка, css, height

Добрый вечер! Потихоньку начал осваивать CSS, поэтому прошу — сильно не пинайте, если вопрос глупый. :)

Произвожу блочную верстку страницы, все вычисления размеров блоков ведутся в %.

Проблема в следующем — поскольку при изменении формата разрешения (4:3 или 16:9) изменяется вычисление параметра widht, как для контейнера (контейнер у меня = 100%), так и для блока (=10%), то весь блок растягивается и превращается в прямоугольник, а мне нужны квадраты.

**Вопрос:** что нужно сделать, чтобы параметр height вычислялся из widht и был ему равен?

То есть как сделать зависимость `height` от `widht`, чтобы `height` подстраивался под `widht`, и тем самым высота блока была равна ширине и при этом параметр `widht` мог бы спокойно "гулять" в зависимости от формата экрана? Получается, `height` должен "гулять" вместе с `widht`... Ну как-то так. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- [Use CSS to Specify the Aspect Ratio of a Fluid Element](http://ansciath.tumblr.com/post/7347495869/css-aspect-ratio)
- [Creating Intrinsic Ratios for Video](http://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video)
- [Адаптивные фоновые изображения](http://habrahabr.ru/post/157817/) (на русском)
- [пример](http://jsfiddle.net/AdQ3P/)

Comment: На основе вашего примера сделал искомое. Там видно, можно сказать —  буквально, то, чего я хотел добиться.

Ссылка вот: http://jsfiddle.net/AdQ3P/346/

Спасибо огромное за ответ! ).
Думаю, можно закрывать.

P.S. Получается, что возможна обратная зависимость, если height и widht местами поменять? Я прав?

Answer (score -1):

```
.square{
    width:20%;
    border:1px solid blue;
}

.square::before{
    content:"";
    display:block;
    padding-top:100%;
}
```

Comment: Вы не могли бы немного прокомментировать Ваше решение?